# Populate columns on newform based on existing item

Tags: 2013, jquery, spservices, edit-form, newform

In custom list, when user selects item and clicks on button or something like that, I would like to load newform with populated columns with values of selected item.

To be more clear, it's like editform but acting as newform because I would like to create **clone**/**replica** of selected item.

I guess this could be done with help of SPServices or something like that, but wasn't able to find something proper.
Also, not able to use infopath nor Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Your best be would be a client-code solution with, like you said, SPServices or REST to pre-populate your new form values.  Place you a CEWP on the new form and place you code there.  This should not be too difficult to accomplish with JavaScript.